# Finishing basement - run electrical to stud wall below steel I beam

Tags: electrical, wiring, basement

I am finishing my basement and I need to run electrical for 2 outlets, 2 wall sconces lights, and a dual gang switch box, and the wall is the 2x4 wall for my stairs, that is also below a steel I beam.

I have a switch there now (on the stair case side) for the light at the bottom of the stairs, and it has conduit running over the beam until it's in between the studs. I have to build a soffit around the HVAC in the photo, but had planned on using the existing 2x4 wall already there. What is the best way (to code) to get wiring in this wall? The backside is under the stairs and will be accessible with a door.

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mSTf.jpg[image]

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to (attempt to) drill through that I-beam to make a run for your wiring. Right? Good, don't attempt that.

It looks like the duct hanger extends about 3/4 of the I-beam, and you'll be sorely tempted to have the bottom of the soffit right under the duct. However, a bit of an air gap significantly reduces the chances of some future person (including future-you) putting a screw through the soffit and into the duct. While you're extending it, bring it down just low enough to slide a new run of NM between the frame of the soffit and the top plate of the wall.

You lose another couple of inches of headroom right there, but with a bit of work, you can dress it up nicely so it's not quite so obnoxious. Consider tapering the end upwards when you get to the door so that someone tall doesn't do a tight turn out of the stairs and smack his head into a bit of wall that only exists at head height...

Comment: I agree, but I'd notch the top wall plate to get the cable or conduit tight to the beam.

Comment: That's a good idea, @isherwood, and thanks for the spell check. :/

Comment: Yes, definitely not drilling through the I beam! So if I notch that top plate and/or OSB used for furring it out, I just need a nail plate to cover where running the Romex through correct? Also, I didn't plan on trying the frame for the soffit into the top plate below the I beam, I had planned on using another 2x2 there to drop it slightly. I do have one more HVAC run to add there first though

Comment: @BigGib yes, that is correct. Put a protection plate over the wiring if the wire is less than 1 1/4" from the surface of the wood. This will protect the wiring from drywall screws, and random "I need to hang something here" nails

Answer (score 0):

You could fur the wall out a bit. Maybe if you remove the flex for reduced clearance you could get by with furring with hat channel or strips of 3/4" OSB with a gap in the OSB where you installed the nailplate.

Oh, don't forget you would need a nailplate where you notch wood or where it crosses past the top plate with less than 1.25" to the front edge of a wood member, even with the flex you have in place.

Comment: The poles actually stick out around 1/4" to 1/2" past the 2x4's so I had already planned on furring it out with OSB, just wasn't sure how to feed the wire through to code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!